# How to prove this condition of inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove this condition: $\langle f(x),f(x)\rangle >0$ if $f(x) \neq 0$.

Given $\langle f(x),f(x) \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 (x^2)(f(x))^2 dx$

Anyone can help?thank you!

Comment: <f(x),f(x)> > 0

Comment: second line : <f(x),f(x)>=

Comment: You can edit the question to include the lines you have written in the comments. Also have look at [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It will help you format your questions to improve readibility.

Comment: Is $f$ assumed to be continuous? For instance, we could have $$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & x = 0 \\ 0 & x \neq 0 \end{array}\right.$$ here $\langle f, f \rangle = 0$, but $f$ is not identically zero.

Comment: As a hint: what do you know about the sign of $x^2$ or of $f(x)^2$? If $f$ is continuous, what implication does the answer to the first question have on the integral in question?

Answer (score 1):

Like the commenters have said, your statement is not true unless you assume other conditions, like continuity (See note 1 below). Or unless when you're saying $f \neq 0$, you're saying $f$ is not in the equivalence class of almost everywhere zero functions. This is a very possible interpretation. This is true, if you look below:

We can prove that if $\langle f(x),f(x)\rangle = 0$ then $f(x) = 0$ almost everywhere (i.e. $f(x) = 0$ on $[-1,1]$  except on a set of Lebesgue measure $0$).

$x^2 (f(x))^2 \geq 0$ on $[-1,1]$.

Now a theorem (see note 2 below) says that if $g$ is non-negative on a set $X$, Lebesgue integrable and $\int_X g d\mu = 0$ then it must be the case that $g = 0$ a.e.

Now your function $x^2(f(x))^2 $ is Riemann-integrable (I am assuming this is given or implicitly assumed), hence Lebesgue integrable. It is also  non-negative everywhere. So this means $x^2(f(x))^2 = 0$ a.e.

$x^2 > 0$ on $[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$, so $(f(x))^2 = 0$ a.e. which implies $f(x) = 0$ a.e.

Note that you don't require continuity of your function for this weaker statement to be true.

Note 1: If $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and not zero somewhere, then consider any point $x_0 \neq 0$ where $f(x) \neq 0$. Such a point must exist, since if $f$ is non-zero somewhere, either it must be non-zero at $x=0$, so it must be non-zero at points close to $x=0$, or non-zero at some $x \neq 0$. Now consider $x^2 (f(x))^2$ on a small interval around $x_0$. Since both $x$ and $f(x)$ are non-zero there, this $x^2 (f(x))^2 > 0$ on this interval. Now consider integrating over this interval.

Note 2: The proof of the theorem is elementary (see proposition 2.3 (e) in the document below):

http://db.math.ust.hk/notes_download/advanced/analysis/e_real_2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There is something[image] for f > 0 that could perhaps cause some misfortune (I don´t know)

Comment: I was wrong thinking 0 at the place of -1. Sorry.